# Why my image is not display immediately after downloaded?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, uiscrollview

I am having problem with async programming.I have a `UIScrollView` which will display multiple images(3~10) when I enter into detail view.So,there are two process that I currently working on.First,When I enter to the detail view,the post request which will call api to display detail data(images and data).Second,when I get the detail data,I have to download the images again which are from array(images with url).

I dont know whats wrong with my code.And also I am new to async programming.

My problem is when I first enter to UIScrollView,which was stucking at indicator

http://puu.sh/ijggV/fa90d7baed.png

When I go to the UITableViewCell and enter to UIScrollView again after three photo was downloaded,

http://puu.sh/ijgkN/d356f521b7.png

Is that because of ViewWillAppear?
When I tried ViewDidLoad,the images doesn't show and stuck at loading even I change the tab multiple times

Here is my View Controller

```
import UIKit
import Kingfisher

class SecondViewController: UIViewController,AuctionAPIProtocol{

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var imageIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

var api : AuctionAPI?
var preferredViews: [UIView]!
var detailData : [AuctionModel] = []
var images = [UIImage]()

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    api = AuctionAPI(delegate: self)

    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    //let images = [UIImage(named: "Image1")!, UIImage(named: "Image2")!, UIImage(named: "Image3")!]
    self.preferredViews = [UIView]()

    if self.detailData.isEmpty{
        self.imageIndicator?.center
        self.imageIndicator?.startAnimating()

        // Start call the api to get the detail data
        self.getAuctionDetailPhotos()
        println("Auction Call")
    }

    // When the api get the detail data and downloaded the images,the image will show in the scroll view
    if images != []{
        println("Condition 1 In")
        let photos : [UIImage] = self.images
        for image in photos {
            let preferredView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height))
            let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height))
            imageView.image = image
            imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
            imageView.clipsToBounds = true
            preferredView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
            imageView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
            preferredView.addSubview(imageView)
            scrollView.addSubview(preferredView)

            preferredViews.append(preferredView)
        }
        self.imageIndicator?.stopAnimating()
    }
}

func getAuctionDetailPhotos(){
    api?.getAuctionDetail()
}

// This is one of the method from AuctionAPIProtocol which will went into results using delegate after API Request done
func didGetTheDetail(results: NSDictionary) {
    var detail : NSDictionary = results["body"] as! NSDictionary
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
        self.detailData = AuctionModel.dictWithJSON(detail)
        println("Auction Call Ended")
        if !(self.detailData.isEmpty){

            var urlString = self.detailData[0].images as [String]

            for url in urlString {

                let imageUrl = NSURL(string: url)
                // This is image downloading library that i using now named Kingfisher                    

                         KingfisherManager.sharedManager.retrieveImageWithURL(imageUrl!, optionsInfo: nil,
                            progressBlock: nil, completionHandler: { (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) -> () in

                        if var dimage = image {
                            self.images.append(dimage)
                            println("Photo Download Completed")
                            //println(self.images)
                        } else {
                            println("Error Downloading images")
                        }
                })
            }
        }
    })
}


override func updateViewConstraints() {
    super.updateViewConstraints()

    if !(images.isEmpty){
        println("Condtion 2 In")
        var prevView: UIView? = nil
        for preferredView in preferredViews {
            let imageView = preferredView.subviews[0] as! UIImageView
            preferredView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[imageView]|",
                options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["imageView": imageView]))
            preferredView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[imageView]|",
                options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["imageView": imageView]))

            if prevView == nil {
                scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[preferredView(==scrollView)]",
                    options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["scrollView": scrollView, "preferredView": preferredView]))
            } else {
                scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[prevView][preferredView(==scrollView)]",
                    options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["scrollView": scrollView, "prevView": prevView!, "preferredView": preferredView]))
            }
            scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[preferredView(==scrollView)]",
                options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["scrollView": scrollView, "preferredView": preferredView]))

            prevView = preferredView
        }
    }
}


override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    if !(images.isEmpty){
        println("Condition 3 In")
        let contentWidth = CGFloat(preferredViews.count) * scrollView.bounds.width
        let contentHeight = scrollView.bounds.height
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(contentWidth, contentHeight)
    }
}

}
```

Any help please?I really need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to put the "if images != []{}" block currently in the `viewWillAppear` into the Kingfisher's downloading completion handler. And since you are downloading multiple images, a `dispatch group` will help you to wait all downloads get over.

I am not sure if it works for you, but I made a little change based on your code. You can find it [here](https://gist.github.com/onevcat/688070bbe2dba52d3d9a).

Comment: I got it now sir.Thanks for your help!!!Really love to use your library.But,i have a question,will it download the images over and over again every time that i come in to UIScrollView Tab?

Comment: No, by default downloaded images will be cached in your memory and disk. It will load them from memory when you enter that screen again. If your user closed your app and reopen it, the images will be retrieved from disk instead until they expired (1 week by default).